# Pycryptodome can't decrypt data

Tags: python, pycryptodome

Why cipher3 can't decrypt cipher data?

- cipher2 and cipher3 use same nonce, but cipher3 can't decrypt data

Code:

```
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES

>>> cipher = AES.new(b"M"*16, AES.MODE_EAX)
>>> cipher2 = AES.new(b"M"*16, AES.MODE_EAX, cipher.nonce)
>>> cipher3 = AES.new(b"M"*16, AES.MODE_EAX, cipher.nonce)

>>> data = cipher.encrypt(b"Hello")
>>> data2 = cipher.encrypt(b"World")

>>> cipher2.decrypt(data)
b'Hello'
>>> cipher3.decrypt(data2)
b'S\xa5\x92\xa2\x9a'
>>> cipher2.decrypt(data2)
b'World'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that cipher objects you use for decryption (`cipher2`, `cipher3` in your case) must be presented the pieces of ciphertext **in the same order they were produced** (by `cipher` in your case).

Instead, you are passing `data2` as the first piece of ciphertext to `cipher3`, even though it was produced second.

This is applicable to several other cipher modes, not just EAX.

Note also that EAX is an **authenticated cipher mode**: you should use the method `decrypt_and_verify()` unless you have were good reasons not to.